# Alert only on first load iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

How do I alert with a UIAlertView when the app is only opened for the first time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save a flag indicating that the alert has been shown and check it prior to showing it. Save it in a file or in the user defaults.